# How do I close the last open window whenever I click the button in js

Tags: javascript

```
<body>
  <script>
    var myWindow;
    function win_open() {
      myWindow = window.open('https://www.imdb.com/?ref_=nv_home');
    }

    function win_close() {
      if (myWindow != null) myWindow.close(myWindow);
    }
  </script>
  <input type="button" value="Open Window" onclick="win_open()" />
  <input type="button" value="Close Window" onclick="win_close()" />
</body>
```

if I click the close Window button it only close the open tab once 
how can I keep closing the tab whenever I clicked it

Comment: What do you mean by it only closes the "open tab once"? If you click open, then close it works, and then if you click open and close again it works. Are you asking how to close multiple tabs if you click the open button multiple times?

Comment: yes! I mean that if I click the "Open Window" botton it keeps opening the imdb website in new tab whenever I click the button but in the case of "Close Window" botton it only works with the latest open imdb site just 'once' no matter how many time i click it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep an array of all your open windows by pushing newly opened ones into the array with `.push()`. Then, whenever you click the close button, you can use `myWindows.pop()` to get the last opened window, which you can then invoke `.close()` on to close.

```
<input type="button" value="Open Window" onclick="win_open()" />
<input type="button" value="Close Window" onclick="win_close()" />

<script>
  var myWindows = [];

  function win_open() {
    myWindows.push(window.open("https://www.imdb.com/?ref_=nv_home"));
  }

  function win_close() {
    if (myWindows.length > 0)
      myWindows.pop().close();
  }
</script>
```

**Note:** The [`.close()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close#:~:text=The%20Window.,a%20script%20using%20the%20Window.&text=content%E2%80%8BWindow%20.) method doesn't expect an argument, the window which gets closed is the window which it is invoked on.

Answer (score 0):

Don't the pass the **myWindow** reference to the close function. Check below code.

Also try to set **"_blank"** parameter in the **window.open** function which will open window in new tab.

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>Class</title>
   <script>

   var myWindow;
    function win_open() {
      myWindow = window.open("https://www.imdb.com/?ref_=nv_home", "_blank");
    } 

      function win_close() {
        if (myWindow != null)  myWindow.close(); 
      }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="button" value="Open Window" onclick="win_open()"/>
   <input type="button" value="Close Window" onclick="win_close()"/>
</body>

</html>
```